# Visual Studio "15" Installer file system path?

Tags: visual-studio, uninstallation

Uninstall of Visual Studio "15" Preview 5 failed but is now no longer available from list of installed programs. But the un/installer should still be there I guess - what's the file system path to it?

Comment: Hi Bent, did your issue is solved or not?

Comment: The issue remains unsolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To completely uninstall the VS “15” Preview versions, you can see [this](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/productinfo/visual-studio-15-FAQ)

•   Launch the Microsoft Visual Studio Installer from the start menu.

•   Uninstall Visual Studio from the installer.

•   From Add / Remove Programs (Windows 7) or Programs and Features (Windows 8.1 and 10), select Microsoft Visual Studio Installer and uninstall.

•   Delete %ProgramData%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Packages.

•   Delete the Visual Studio folder (normally under %ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio\VS15Preview).

Comment: "Launch the Microsoft Visual Studio Installer from the start menu." -- there is no such thing available in my list of programs through the start menu or from the list of installed programs via the control panel.

Comment: @BentRasmussen, it looks like the installer instance of the Visual Studio "15" Preview 5 already be removed, you can directly delete this 2 installation folders:  %ProgramData%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Packages and %ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio\VS15Preview, then the uninstallation is complete.

Comment: To confirm the uninstallation is successful or not, you can try to run the Visual Studio "15" Preview 5 installer (the installer that you downloaded from Microsoft download website) and it should display the installation page. If the preview installed Visual Studio "15" Preview 5 still not be removed, there should only display several buttons like ‘Modify’, ‘Launch’ and the ‘hamburger’ menu drop-down.

Comment: @BentRasmussen, does your issue is solved or not? If not, please share your current condition with us.

Comment: I've followed the instructions; I don't know if there are any leftovers in the registry but I consider it uninstalled for now. I will try the next preview version too and if that causes problems I guess I can repair it.

Comment: @BentRasmussen, I also tried to follow the steps in my reply to uninstall my VS “15” Preview 5, and it works fine and I can successfully install the VS “15” Preview 5 again, you should have a try with the new installation and if meet any issue, feel free to show it.